# node.js "undefined" mysteriously appears

Tags: javascript, node.js, undefined

I have the following node.js files:

```
//test.js:
var hash=require('./hash');
var sys=require('sys');

sys.puts(hash.hash("asdf","asdf"));
```

and

```
//hash.js:
var exec=require('child_process').exec;
var sys=require('sys');

exports.hash=function(data,hash_type){
        exec('pwd',function callback(error,stdout,stderr){
                sys.puts(stdout);
        });
}
```

When I do `node test.js`, I get the following output:

```
eamorr@Compaq6000:~/Desktop/simple-hash$ node test.js 
undefined
/home/hynese/Desktop/nodejs-simple-hash
```

Why am I getting "undefined"??? I'm really stuck here...

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Many thanks in advance,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change:

```
sys.puts(hash.hash("asdf","asdf"));
```

to just:

```
hash.hash("asdf","asdf");
```

You're outputting the return value of `hash.hash`, although since you didn't provide a return value, the language returns undefined, which is then outputted to the screen. You already output the result of the system command in the callback, so you don't need another `sys.puts`.

As a side note, you probably don't need to name that callback function `callback`.